# Html Tag parser in Haskell

Tags: html, parsing, haskell

Hi I have an assignment which is supposed to check given a string if it can become a valid html file. like for example running this:

```
doc2 = “<head> Test2 <body> Testing </body>"
```

should output this:

```
λ parse hmtl doc2
(False, “<head> Test2 <body> Testing </body>”)
```

the trouble I am having is creating a parser for the tags. 
I know that there is a package, but we are not allowed to use it. Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: [Don't use regular expressions.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Comment: Also, after you turn in your assignment, take a look at the source code of the package. Haskell is easy to read for the most part.

Comment: The question is very broad....  Can you use parser packages?  Which one, parsec, happy (the approaches are very different)?  Do you have to write a parser from first principles?  Are you building for performance?

Comment: @PyRulez that doesn't really help me writing the function.

Comment: @jamshidh we can not use any parser packages. We have to write a parser from first principles. No performance does not matter.

Comment: @user3324236 Okay, sorry. This may be more helpful: http://dev.stephendiehl.com/fun/002_parsers.html